# How do you share a Kindle books with your notes / hightlights, with another user?

Tags: sharing, kindle, kindle-cloud-reader

Is it possible to share a Kindle book you are reading, along with your notes and highlights?

I know you can lend it to them; I've done that before, but the person I borrowed it from didn't have any notes or highlights.